# How to configure axes and set explicit axis start and end points on a line chart in iOS 16.0's Swift Charts

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

In this code I declare a Chart with an x scale domain between two doubles:

```
Chart(points, id: \.self) { point in
    LineMark(
        x: .value("time/s", point.timestamp),
        y: .value("potential/mV", point.potential)
    )
    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Electrode", point.electrode.symbol))
}
.chartXScale(domain: timeWindow)
// ...
```

where `timeWindow` is declared as follows:

```
var timeWindow: ClosedRange<Double> {
    doc.contents.time(at: window.lowerBound)...doc.contents.time(at: window.upperBound)
}
```

and `time` is defined as:

```
func time(at index: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(index) * (1 / sampleRate)
}
```

However, the chart x-axis this produces does not have a start and end at the lower and upper bounds of the `ClosedRange<Double>` I have provided, rather there is a section of mystery space on either the left and right side of the plots:

[image: Empty space in the Chart on the right of the LineMark plot.]

How can I get the chart to adhere to the domain I have provided (the bounds are also displayed in the text view of the bottomBar ToolbarItemGroup, using the code `Text("\(timeWindow.lowerBound.format()) s to \(timeWindow.upperBound.format()) s")`)? And how can I get the y-axis to render on the left of the chart?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72902724/12299030? (similar question was for Y-axis)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you, but now confused as to what chartXScale is actually meant to do :/

Comment: @Tahmid My impression is that chartXScale and chartYScale are only used as a guideline and Chart loosely goes by them when generating the chart. Maybe that will improve in future versions.

Comment: You do lose the automatic mark stride by length by using the axis marks method, but since im using the chart to sort of ‘scroll’ through data, it makes sense to use it and make it explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to create an array of values, enabling the construction of axis content by using `AxisMarks`:

```
var xValues: [Double] {
    stride(from: timeWindow.lowerBound, to: timeWindow.upperBound, by: (timeWindow.upperBound - timeWindow.lowerBound) / 5).map { $0 }
}
```

And then in the chart modifiers:

```
Chart(points, id: \.self) { point in
    LineMark(
        x: .value("time/s", point.timestamp),
        y: .value("potential/mV", point.potential)
    )
    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Electrode", point.electrode.symbol))
}
.chartXScale(domain: ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: timeWindow.lowerBound, upper: timeWindow.upperBound)))
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: xValues)
}
    \\ ...
```

N.B.: I have found that it is still necessary to include the `chartXScale(domain:)` modifier, as otherwise the x-axis seems to always begin at zero, even if that is not included in the axis marks.

This produces the intended behaviour for the 'scrollable' plot:

[image: Intended scrollable plot.]

However, there is a drawback of now losing the automatic method of determining mark spacing in the axis, but this is a compromise I will have to deal with, and construct a better algorithm for creating them instead of hard coded values like the `5` used above.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, i do ont understand the chartXAxis part and chartXScale. My case scenario is a date object so that's .chartXScale(domain: ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: $0.date.lowerBound, upper: $0.date.upperBound)))
                        .chartXAxis {
                            AxisMarks(values: stride(from: $0.date.lowerBound, to: $0.date.upperBound, by: ($0.date.upperBound - $0.date.lowerBound) / 5).map { $0 })
                        } ?